# Red Priests/Priestesses and their tokens

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In S06E01 of the series we get to discover that

> Melisandre's necklace is a great source of her powers.

Is it plausible that all Red Priests/Priestesses have a token of their own from which they can channel their powers? If so, what are the possible tokens of the other Red Priests/Priestesses that we’ve seen?

I'm fine with answers from both books and series.

This is my first question so be gentle :)

Comment: This might be flagged as speculative answers, but I'm positive that I can edit the question to be more canon-proof if that's the case. Please help me with that instead of downvoting. This is my first question on Scifi-Exchange.

Comment: No matter what, it's all just speculation. Melisandre has been shown in the show without her ruby, and in the books there's no explanation so far (except that for one glamour by Melisandre of another character a ruby was used).

Comment: @alexwlchan I kindly disagree with the edit you made that removed the "possible tokens"-statement. I know that no other token have been confirmed in the show or books. I'm thinking of for example the sword for Thoros of myr (Or maybe his wine sack). These are possible tokens, but of course not confirmed ones.

Comment: @Spoek Sorry, a slightly heavy-handed edit. Thanks for reverting!

Comment: @Spoek Thoros's sword can not be his "token" because Thoros used a  new sword for each joust.

Comment: Nope. Melisandre is a rogue. What she does is of her own accord. See my answers [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117098/21267) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67163/21267). The things she does are so far unique to her.